# Play 2.5.x in Docker container not updating through shared folder

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, docker, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm running a development environment for Play Framework 2.5.x in a Docker container. The application works, and I can view it on my browser through the shared port. However, the auto-update feature does not work.

From research I've learned this is because Play's JNotify doesn't poll file changes in shared folders. I've tried the solution to this problem, which is simply polling at a time interval by adding the following to `build.sbt`

`PlayKeys.fileWatchService := play.runsupport.FileWatchService.sbt(pollInterval.value)`

After making this change (and making sure it was pushed through the shared folder), using `activator run` successfully compiles and runs the server.

```
[info] Done updating.

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

I can view it in my browser. However, on changing a file, no recompilation happens and refreshing doesn't change anything. Stopping and starting the server however does show the change.

I think I may know why, but I don't know how to solve it. I've read that using `activator ~run` supposedly starts the server, but uses SBT instead of activator. When I use this command to start the server, it hangs at:

`[info] Set current project to example-user-app in build file:/home/example-user/example-user-app)`